# How to get positive response for GETCHALLENGE request in EMV?

Tags: emv

In the case of GETCHALLENGE Request (0084000000), we are getting the positive response in the case of VISA\DEBIT card, but for AMEX and MASTERCARD we are getting the response as 6D00 (Instruction code not supported or invalid).

Answer (score 0):

Not all instructions are supported by all card products. Different card products also support different transaction types, off the top of my head (so take my answer with a grain of salt) get challenge should online be necessary for offline transactions with asymmetric crypto where the terminal needs to identify itself to the card. It's possible (though not likely nowadays) that the card doesn't have a crypto coprocessor capable of handling this, so that code path is disabled. It's also possible that the MC and Amex EMV scheme specifics require a different transaction flow and you're not fulfilling the prerequisites for get challenge.

Without konw the sequence of commands you're sending to the card and the profile on the card, it's difficult to provide more information than the 6D00 is already providing.